# how to view xml as tree in browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

Please tell me how to view the following XML as tree in a browser using `java Server Faces` or `JavaScript function`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: I got two down vote...but not a single answer....

Comment: You may wish to show that you've put some effort in solving this first by showing what you've tried. Then consider asking a more specific question over what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Yahoo! UI tree view can help you:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/